# ModalPopup close after save button clicked jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am working on a code igniter ..In my view page, i have one modal popup. In the modalpopup, i have put form.so what i want is that When user click save button ..the model pop up close through jquery..

this is my save and close  button ... the model is closes fine if i click the close button but because for save button i have given control to the jquery so i want to close there which i dont know

```
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> 
   <a id = "save" class="btn x" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</a>



   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#save').click(function() { //  $("#form").serialize()

var check_no = $('#check_no').val();
var form_data = {
        check_no: $('#check_no').val(),


};



$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('checkDetailsController/addCheckDetails'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg.res == 1)
        {
            alert('true')

        }
        else{
            alert("false");          
          }


    }
});

return false;
     });


  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The save function must use $('#dialog').dialog("close"); instead of $(this).dialog('close'). This causes the close method attached to dialog object to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the dialog from jqueryUI you can use the buttons option.

```
$('#yourcontainer').dialog({
        buttons : {
            // Save and close button
            'Save' : function () {
                // your javascript code for saving
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            // Cancel button
            'Close' : function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        // and your other settings
    });
```

Comment: well i am able to close the button through data dismiss ..so how can i add data dismiss after save button is clicked in jquery